# How do I return a value from a Helper Class to a view controller?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I have a viewcontroller that calls a HelperClass class method in its viewDidLoad like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.usersArray = [SantiappsHelper fetchUsers];    
}
```

That class method looks like this:

```
+(NSArray *)fetchUsers{

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myserver.com/myApp/getusers.php"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];

__block NSArray *usersArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Peform the request
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                 returningResponse:&response
                                                             error:&error];
    if (error) {
        // Deal with your error
        if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
            NSLog(@"HTTP Error: %d %@", httpResponse.statusCode, error);
            return;
        }
        NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
        return;
    }

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"responseString fetchUsers %@", responseString);

    NSLog(@"inside of block");

    usersArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];

});
NSLog(@"outside of block");
return usersArray;
```

}

The responseString is printed out just fine.  But how do I return that value to my view controller?  Because its a tableview controller which already loads its tableview before any of the data is gotten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual question is "How is a result returned from an asynchronous method?"

Say, you have an asynchronous task "doSomethingAsync" (which is a class method or instance method or a function, but this doesn't really matter).

The familiar *synchronous form*  "doSomething" would simply return the result and can be declared as follows:

`- (Result*) doSomething;`

The equivalent asynchronous task "doSomethingAsync" can be declared using a *completion handler*:

```
typedef void (^completion_block_t)(Result* result)
- (void) doSomethingAsync:(completion_block_t)completionHandler;
```

Example:

Suppose a class "MyClass" defines a property "result" which will be initialized from the result of an asynchronous class method (class Foo). You retrieve the result in the method "fetchResult":

```
- (void) fetchResult {
    [Foo doSomethingAsync:^(Result* result){
        self.result = result;
    }];
}
```

It may take a while to grasp what's going on here and it requires you to "think asynchronous" ;)

The important thing to realize is, that the completion handler is a block - which is defined *inline* and treated as if it were a normal object. The block is created by the call site and passed as an argument for the parameter *completionHandler* to the `doSomethingAsync:` method. The block itself defines the actions to take when the asynchronous task completes.

On the other hand, the asynchronous method internally must keep a reference to this block until it completes. Then, it must call the block and provide its result as an argument to the parameter *result* of the completion block.

---

There are other forms to "return" the result of an asynchronous function. One common pattern is to use a *Future* or a *Promise*. A Future or Promise simply represents the *eventual* result of an asynchronous function. It is an *object* that can be *immediately* returned from the asynchronous function - but its *value* (the result of the asynchronous task) is available only later when the asynchronous task finished. The task MUST eventually set a value for the promise when it finishes. This is called "resolving". That means, that the task must keep a reference to that returned promise object, and finally "resolve" it with either a value meaning *success* or a value meaning *failure*.

Assuming there is such a class "Promise", this would let you declare asynchronous methods like this:

`- (Promise*) doSomethingAsync;`

An implementation of a Promise may be fully support the "asynchronous model". In order to retrieve the result, you simply define what to do when the result is available. A particular implementation of a Promise may accomplish this for example:

```
- (void) fetchResult {
    Promise* promise = [Foo doSomethingAsync];
    promise.then(^(Result* result){
        self.result = result;
    });
}
```

Notice the "then", which is actually a *property* of the class Promise that returns a *block*:

```
@property then_block_t then;
```

This returned block of type "then_block_t" is immediately called via:

```
promise.then(...)
```

Much like:

```
then_block_t block = promise.then;
block( ... );
```

but shorter.

The block of type "then_block_t" has a parameter which is a *completion block* which will be invoked by the promise when the result is eventually available. The completion block is defined inline:

```
^(Result* result){ ... }
```

As you can see, the *completion block* has a parameter *result* which is the actual result of the asynchronous method.

OK, now your head may spin ;)

But now, go back to the example

```
    Promise* promise = [Foo doSomethingAsync];
    promise.then(^(Result* result){
        self.result = result;
    });
```

which simply reads:

- "Start asynchronous method [Foo doSomethingAsync] and return a
  promise.
- When finished *then* execute the block where the result of task
  "doSomethingAsync" is passed with the argument *result*."

You can it write even shorter:

```
[Foo doSomethingAsync]
.then(^(Result* result) {
    self.result = result;
};
```

which is akin to the form with the completion handler:

```
[Foo doSomethingAsync:^(Result* result){
    self.result = result;
}];
```

---

The most important feature of a Promise, though, is that it allows us to "chain" two or more asynchronous tasks together. This is made possible since the block of type `then_block_t` which is returned from the property `then` has a return value of type `Promise`.

`typedef Promise* (^then_block_t)(completion_block_t onSuccess);`

I'm pretty sure your head is spinning now in high frequency ;) - thus, an example will make this clear (hopefully):

Suppose you have two asynchronous methods: asyncA and asyncB. The first requires an input, processes it asynchronously and produces a result. The second method asyncB should take this result, process it asynchronously and finally print out @"OK" or an NSError - if something went wrong:

```
[self asyncA:input]
.then(^(OutputA* outA) {
    return [self asyncB:outA];
})
.then(^(OutputB* outB){
    NSLog(@"end result: %@", outB);
    return nil;
});
```

This reads:

- "Asynchronously perform task "asyncA".
- When finished *then* asynchronously perform task "asyncB".
- If finished, *then* print out result."

You may notice that a handler will return a *Promise* object in the statement

`return [self asyncB:outA];`.

This will establish the "chain" form task "asyncA" to "asyncB". The eventual "value" of the returned promise will then appear as the *result* parameter in next handler.

A handler may also return an *immediate* result which happens to end up as the *result* parameter in the next handler as well.

---

An *actual* implementation in Objective-C differs slightly, in that the *then_block_t* has *two* parameters: one for the success case and one for the failure case:

`typedef Promise* (^then_block_t)(completion_block_t onSuccess, failure_block_t onFailure);`

I left this out in the former samples for brevity. An actual implementation would look like this:

```
[self asyncA:input]
.then(^(OutputA* out) {
    return [self asyncB:out];
}, nil)
.then(^(id result){
    NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
    return nil;
}, ^id(NSError*error){
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
    return nil;
});
```

---

Anther cool feature of promises is that errors will be forwarded through the chain of promises. That means, one can have multiple "chained" tasks say, A, B, C, D  where only the success handler is defined. The last handler (pair) defines an error handler. If an error occurs in the first async task - that error will be forwarded through all promises until an error handler finally handles it. Success handlers will only be called when the task succeeded, and the error handler will only be called when the task failed:

```
[self A]
.then(^(id result) {
    return [self B:result];
}, nil)
.then(^(id result) {
    return [self C:result];
}, nil)
.then(^(id result) {
    return [self D:result];
}, nil)

.then(^(id result) {
    NSLog(@"Success");
    return nil;
}, ^id(NSError*error){
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
    return nil;
});
```

There's more regarding Promises, but well beyond this SO answer.

An example for an implementation can be found here: [RXPromise](https://github.com/couchdeveloper/RXPromise)

Comment: That looks pretty cool - I've never used that structure in Obj-C before, only something similar in c#

Comment: Thanks ;)  The implementation of RXPromise follows the [Promises/A+](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec) specification - which was originally designed for Javascript. And you are right, Promises have an _astonishing_ simple API and are _extremely_ powerful. RXPromise also implements cancellation.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper thanks, that's quite an answer.  Great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

Add the following to SantiappsHelper.h

```
typedef void (^Handler)(NSArray *users);
```

In viewDidLoad, change

```
self.usersArray = [SantiappsHelper fetchUsers];
```

to

```
[SantiappsHelper fetchUsersWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *users) {
    self.usersArray = users;
}];
```

Change

```
+(NSArray *)fetchUsers{
```

to

```
+(void)fetchUsersWithCompletionHandler:(Handler)handler {
```

in both .m and .h files.

And in this method, right after

```
usersArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
```

add

```
if (handler)
    handler(usersArray);
```

Remove

```
return usersArray;
```

I think that should do. Also, execute the handler block on the main thread if that's desired.

Comment: This is great!  Can I bother you for a brief explanation?

Comment: You use a block to prepare usersArray. That's executed asynchronously. When you return from the helper method, likely your usersArray is not available yet. That's why it is not working. By providing a completion handler to the helper method, the helper method calls your completion handler when the usersArray becomes available. You actually can add more logic to the completion handler if needed. Hope this helps.