# Passing data between classes / asynchronous requests / iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, oop

I am converting my application from Syncronous to Asyncronous HTTP requests and have ran into a problem that looks like it will require quite a big reworking of how the application handles its data.  Let me try to explain

Previously it was like this:

-`Class1`, `Class2` and `Class3` were all subclasses of `UIViewController`
 -Helper class
 -Content display class

They do broadly different things but the common trait is their interaction with the helper class.  They gather details of a request in a number of different ways from a user and then eventually send a request to the helper class.
When it was done syncronously the helper class would return the data.  Each class would then interpret the data (XML files) and pass them on to the Content display class via a segue

**So something broadly like this:**

Class1:

```
//Get user input
SomeData *data = [helperclass makerequest];
id vcData = [data process];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier"];
---
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    DestinationViewController *destination = (DestinationViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    destination.data = vcData;
}
```

Content display class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.data presentdata];
}
```

**Now it looks like this**

I dealt with this problem by first making it work with Class1 with a view to deploying the fix to class2 and class3.  So class1 and helper now interact like this

Class1:

```
//Get user input
SomeData *data = [helperclass makerequestWithSender:self];
id vcData = [data process];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier"];
---
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    DestinationViewController *destination = (DestinationViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    destination.data = vcData;
}
```

Now the biggest problem I am facing is how to get the data from helperclass back to `Class1`.  I managed to get it to work by doing

```
(void)makeRequestWithSender:(Class1*)sender
{
  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:...
     {
        [sender sendData:data];
     }
}
```

However, when I have came to roll this out to the other 2 GUI classed which will compose the request I am having difficulty with.  My first thought was to set `sender:(id)` but that fails at the line `[sender sendData:data]` telling me that `id` does not have an method `sendData:` or similar.

Hopefully I wasn't too vague here and you guys can help.  If required I will be able to post code snippets but for now can anyone help with a better suggestion about how to structure the code for this request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically want to use the 'observer pattern' or a (maybe) slightly changed setup, so you can use delegation.

**Observer pattern**

You gain the mechanic via the [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSNotifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Your 3 different UIViewController subclasses each subscribe to a specific NSNotification and you notify them via posting a notification via the NSNotificationCenter.

The following code is an example of how you can approach the problem in your viewcontroller subclasses:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // subscribe to a specific notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doSomethingWithTheData:) name:@"MyDataChangedNotification" object:nil];
}
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];  
    // do not forget to unsubscribe the observer, or you may experience crashes towards a deallocated observer
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
...
- (void)doSomethingWithTheData:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // you grab your data our of the notifications userinfo
    MyDataObject *myChangedData = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"myChangedDataKey"];
    ...
}
```

In your helper class, after the data changed you have to inform the observers, e.g.

```
-(void)myDataDidChangeHere {
    MyDataObject *myChangedData = ...;
    // you can add you data to the notification (to later access it in your viewcontrollers)
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyDataChangedNotification" object:nil userInfo:@{@"myChangedDataKey" : myChangedData}];
}
```

**via @protocol**

Presuming all your UIViewController subclasses reside in a parent viewcontroller, you can implement a protocol in your helper class and make the parent viewcontroller the delegate. Then the parent viewcontroller may inform the child uiviewcontrollers via passing a message.

Your helper class declaration could look like this (presuming ARC):

```
@protocol HelperDelegate;

@interface Helper : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<HelperDelegate> delegate;

...
@end

@protocol HelperDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)helper:(Helper *)helper dataDidChange:(MyDataObject*)data;

@end
```

In the helper implementation you would inform the delegate via:

```
...
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(helper:dataDidChange:)]) {
    [self.delegate helper:self dataDidChange:myChangedDataObject];
}
...
```

Your parent viewcontroller would need to be the delegate of the helper class and implement its protocol; a rough sketch, in the declaration

```
@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController <HelperDelegate>
```

and for the implementation in short version

```
// you alloc init your helper and assign the delegate to self, also of course implement the delegate method

-(void)helper:(Helper *)helper dataDidChange:(MyDataObject*)data {
    [self.myCustomChildViewController doSomethingWithTheNewData:data];
}
```

**Besides..**

You might ask yourself which method to prefer. Both are viable, the main difference is that via the observer pattern you get more objects to be informed 'at once', whereas a protocol can only have one delegate and that one has to forward the message if needed. There are a lot of discussions around about pros and cons. I'd suggest you read up on them once you made up your mind (sorry ain't got enough reputation to post more than two links, so please search on stackoverflow). If something is unclear, please ask.

Comment: Observer pattern turned out to be perfect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some reasonable ideas here.  To elaborate/add my opinion:

First, which object ought to tell the downloader (`HelperClass`) to begin downloading?  My practice is to do this in the view controller that will present the data.  So I generally start network requests after a segue (like in `viewWillAppear:` of the presented vc), not before.

Next, when one class needs to execute code provided for another, I first think about if it makes sense to do it using a `block`.  Very often (not always) blocks make more sense and provide more readable code than, say, delegate, notification, KVO, etc.  I think NSURLConnection completion, for example, is better suited to blocks than delegate.  (and Apple kind of agrees, having introduced `+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler`).

So my pattern for your app would be this:

```
// Class1.m

// when user has completed providing input
...
// don't do any request yet.  just start a segue
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ToContentDisplayClass" sender:self];
...

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    // don't do a request yet, just marshall the data needed for the request
    // and send it to the vc who actually cares about the request/result

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ToContentDisplayClass"]) {

        NSArray *userInput = // collect user input in a collection or custom object
        ContentDisplayClass *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.dataNeededForRequest = userInput;
    }
    ...
```

Then in ContentDisplayClass.m

```
// this is the class that will present the result, let it make the request

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    HelperClass *helper = [[HelperClass alloc]
                              initWithDataNeededForRequest:self.dataNeededForRequest];

    // helper class forms a request using the data provided from the original vc,
    // then...

   [helper sendRequestWithCompletion:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // interpret data, update view
            self.label.text = // string we pulled out of data
        } else {
            // present an AlertView? dismiss this vc?
        }
    }];
```

This depends on `HelperClass` implementing the `block` form of `NSURLConnection`

```
// HelperClass.m

- (id)initWithDataNeededForRequest:(id)dataNeededForRequest {
   // standard init pattern, set properties from the param
}

- (void)sendRequestWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *, NSData *, NSError *))completion {

    NSURLRequest *request = ...
    // the stuff we need to formulate the request has been setup in init
    // use NSURLConnection block method

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
        queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
        completionHandler:completion];
}
```

Edit - there are several rationale's for making the VC transition before starting the network request:

1) Build the standard behavior around the success case: unless the app is about testing network connections, the success case is that the request works.

2) The cardinal principal for an app is to be responsive, to do something sensible immediately upon user actions.  So when the user does something to initiate the request, an immediate vc transition is good.  (what instead? a spinner?).  The newly presented UI might even reduce the perceived latency of the request by giving user something new to look at while it runs.

3) What should an app do when a request fails?  If the app doesn't really need the request to be useful, then doing nothing is a good option, so you'd want to be on the new vc. More typically, the request is necessary to proceed.  The UI should be "responsive" to request failure, too.  Typical behavior is to present an alert that offers some form of "retry" or "cancel".  For either choice, the place the UI wants to be is on the new vc.  Retry is more obvious, because that's where it always is when it tries to fetch the data.  For cancel, the way to be "responsive" to cancel is to go back to the old vc, a vc transition back isn't ugly, it's what the user just asked for.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of basic answer I was hoping to hear.  I had definitely overcomplicated the issue.  I will give this approach a go and let you know!

Comment: This would have worked but I chose to use the Observer example above because if the request threw an error your method would have resulted in 2 view changes which was a little ugly.  Thanks though!

Comment: Sure.  To some extent it's a matter of taste, but I think there's strong UI norms to do the quick ui transition.  And the transition back on failure is actually a good correct thing to do, not - imo - ugly.  Will edit to add a rationale.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on how you're handling the data now, but to change your data to asynchronous calls, I would use blocks. For instance your current synchronous code like this:

```
//Get user input
data = [helperclass makerequest]
sendData = [data process]
```

would turn into something like this:

```
//Get user input
data = [helperclass makerequestWithSuccess:^{
    sendData = [data process]
}];
```

Using a success block will allow you to wait to process the data until the `makerequest` was finished.

Your new `makerequest` function would now look like this:

```
-(void)makerequestWithSuccess:(void (^)(void))success{
     // Put your makerequest code here
     // After your makerequest is completed successfully, call:
     success();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what I've done in the past is relevant to your problem, but what I've done is create a download class that has a `delegate` protocol with a single method: `-(void)downloadFinished:(id) data`.

Any class that needs to get asynchronous data, creates an instance of this download class, and sets itself as the `delegate`. I call `downloadFinished:` from both `connection:didFailWithError:` and `connectionDidFinishLoading:`. Then, in the implementation of that method in the delegate, I check whether the data's class is `NSData` or `NSError`, and evaluate that data however is appropriate for that class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood your problem correctly, but if it's sort of:

1. Start task A asynchronously.
2. When task A finished successfully, get its result and start task B whose input is result A.
3. When task B finished successfully, get its result and start task C whose input is result B.
4. ...
5. When finished successfully, be happy, otherwise print error.

A code example would look like this:

```
typedef (void)(^completion_block_t)(id result);

-(void) asyncTaskA:(completion_block_t)completionHandler;
-(void) asyncTaskBWithInput:(id)input completion:(completion_block_t)completionHandler;    
-(void) asyncTaskCWithInput:(id)input completion:(completion_block_t)completionHandler;
-(void) asyncSomethingWithCompletion:(completion_block_t)completionHandler;

-(void) asyncSomethingWithCompletion:(completion_block_t)completionHandler
{
    [self asyncTaskA:^(id resultA){
        if (![resultA isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
            [self asyncTaskBWithInput:resultA completion:^(id resultB){
                if (![resultB isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
                    [self asyncTaskCWithInput:resultB completion:^(id resultC) {
                        completionHandler(resultC);                         
                    }];
                }
                else {
                    completionHandler(resultB); // error;
                }
            }];
        }
        else {
            completionHandler(resultA); // error
        }    
    }];
}
```

And you use it like:

```
[self asyncSomethingWithCompletion:^(id result){
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
    }
    else {
        // success!
        self.myData = result;
    }
}];
```

The "continuation" and error handling makes this a bit confusing (and Objective-C syntax doesn't really add for more readability).

---

#### Another example with a third party library support:

The same logic can be written as this:

```
-(Promise*) asyncTaskA;
-(Promise*) asyncTaskBWithInput;    
-(Promise*) asyncTaskCWithInput;
-(Promise*) asyncSomething;

- (Promise*) asyncSomething 
{
    return [self asyncTaskA]
    .then(id^(id result) {
       return [self asyncTaskBWithInput:result];
    }, nil)
    .then(id^(id result) {
       return [self asyncTaskCWithInput:result];
    }, nil);
}
```

And it is used as follows:

```
[self asyncSomething]
.then(^(id result) {
    self.myData = result;
    return nil;
},  
^id(NSError* error) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
    return nil;
});
```

If you like the latter more, the "Promise" framework is available on GitHub: [RXPromise](https://github.com/couchdeveloper/RXPromise) - I'm the author ;)

Comment: I'm not 100% that I made my initial question clear enough.  Your description of the process is slightly wide of the mark so I don't know if your answer is completely relevant.

Take the 5. point list you wrote above but consider that point 1. can originate from 3 different unique classes (UIViewControllers) and the one which started the process needs to be notified when the data is recieved & processed.  Is your answer still relvant in this context?

Comment: Yes, 100%. The only prerequisite I made is that gathering infos from three different sources will occur in *sequence*. That is, not running in parallel. But this is usually the case when you request data from a user. In my example these are the asynchronous tasks A, B and C. That these are methods of "self" doesn't really matter. You may exchange "self" with viewController1, viewController2, etc., or whatever . An *asynchronous* task can be anything that is, well asynchronous: a network access, a user's input, etc. Result of task C may simply include result of task A and B, too.

Comment: There is also the possibility to run A, B and C *simultaneously* (and asynchronously). Then,  when *all* tasks have been finished successfully, a call site may proceed with the 3 results in another asynchronous task - whose final result is then processed in the "top" (or originating) call site.  I admit, the examples are a bit "abstract" and may be difficult to "grasp" at first for everybody who is starting to use asynchronous patterns. ;)

Comment: You might look at this similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416683/how-do-i-return-a-value-from-a-helper-class-to-a-view-controller). The answer *might* also help you understanding asynchronous patterns. It also explains how that "Promise" works in detail.